# How to get user input for the column label probeid in this program

Tags: perl, parsing, text

My data has 170 rows (exp.values) and 18,000 columns (Probeid's). If i enter a specific probeId, I need the particular column to be retrieved. And that probeid will be entered during run time. Does anyone have an idea? I have no problem with the output for this program. This program does the task for the id P_170221 that is entered while coding.When I tried entering variable $probeid (which is got by STDIN) in place of P_170221, I got error like:

Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at C:/Users/xxx/perl_workspace/perl_proj_one/GIS/just.pl line 16, <> line 1.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tie::Handle::CSV;
open(OUT,">C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\Output.txt")||die $!;
my $fh = Tie::Handle::CSV->new("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\GE_Acc.csv", header => 1);

while (my $csv_line = <$fh>) {
   print OUT $csv_line->{'FID'} . ", " . $csv_line->{'IID'} .",".$csv_line->{'P_1710221'}."\n";
    my $i++;
}

close $fh;
```

Comment: What does (a small sample of) your input data look like? What output do you want to see? What problems are there with the current output you're getting? Being clear about what you're asking makes it far easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You get a normal hash reference for each line, iterate over its keys. Here I sort the keys because you probably don't want to go through them in random order:

```
while (my $csv_line = <$fh>) {
    print OUT $csv_line->{'FID'} . ", " . $csv_line->{'IID'};
    foreach my $key (sort keys %$csv_line) {
        # Ignore columns that aren't probeids
        next if $key eq 'FID' or $key eq 'IID';  

        print ", " . $csv_line->{$key};
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: Hi Palant, If i want to ask the user to key in the probeid at run time, I tried with a variable, but it shows 
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at C:/Users/xxx/perl_workspace/perl_proj_one/GIS/just.pl line 16, <> line 1.